# Both login and signup in same view in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want my login and sign up views in same template. Just like this template:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<h1>Sign up</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My login looks like

```
class Login(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'user/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        login(self.request, form.get_user())
        return super(Login, self).form_valid(form)
```

and my sign up view uses form class `UserCreationForm`. How is it possible to have 1 view with different form classes? And what should the two form actions be, so the view can determine whether the user tried to login or sign up?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you can have multiple forms with generic view.

- However, you can keep single form for both operations.
- Hide and unhide fields depending upon user operation.
- Have two submit buttons to identify signup/login operation through form submission.
- Take appropriate action in view depending upon which submit button pressed by user.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to create your MultipleFormView class, like in this solution https://gist.github.com/michelts/1029336

UPD:
Sorry, it's not good solution, because it validates all forms.
Here is a solution based on TemplateView

```
class LoginSignupView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'login_signup.html'
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    login_prefix = 'login'
    signup_prefix = 'signup'

    def check_redirect(self, context):
        redirect_to = context.get(self.redirect_field_name)
        if not redirect_to:
            return settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

        netloc = urlparse.urlparse(redirect_to)[1]
        if netloc and netloc != self.request.get_host():
            return settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

        return redirect_to

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginSignupView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        redirect_to = self.request.REQUEST.get(self.redirect_field_name, '')
        context[self.redirect_field_name] = redirect_to
        context['login_form'] = AuthenticationForm(prefix=self.login_prefix)
        context['signup_form'] = UserCreationForm(prefix=self.signup_prefix)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        redirect_to = self.check_redirect(context)

        if u'login_submit' in self.request.POST:
            login_form = AuthenticationForm(
                prefix=self.login_prefix,
                data=request.POST
            )
            if login_form.is_valid():
                auth_login(request, login_form.get_user())
                if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                    request.session.delete_test_cookie()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
            context['login_form'] = login_form

        if u'signup_submit' in self.request.POST:
            signup_form = UserCreationForm(
                prefix=self.signup_prefix,
                data=request.POST
            )

            if signup_form.is_valid():
                # register user
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
            context['signup_form'] = signup_form

        self.request.session.set_test_cookie()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: It looks like what I need, but I don't know exactly how to use it. Can you give me an example?